# MySQL query - Inner join using only the latest version of an entry

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a table, named `jobs` with various pieces of information.  Each job is given a job number (unique id).

There is then another table, named `purchaseOrders` that has a FK of jobID and a PK of poID.

when a purchase order entry is edited, the old information is saved... meaning, i create a new PO entry (new unique id).

What i'm trying to do, is write one query that **selects all fields from "jobs" and all fields from "purchaseOrders" but only the latest poID for that job**.

For example:

```
jobID      Name      State            poID      time      jobID
==========================            ==========================
1          foo       fl               1         1:00      1
2          bar       ga               2         1:10      1
3          zzz       ny               3         1:20      1
                                      4         2:00      2
                                      5         2:01      2
                                      6         2:30      2
                                      7         3:00      3
                                      8         3:40      3
                                      9         3:15      3
```

How can I run a query that will select all the columns from both tables, but only include the information with the highest poID for the specific jobID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    jobs a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT jobID, MAX(time) maxVal
            FROM purchaseOrders
            GROUP BY jobID
        ) b ON a.jobID = b.jobID
        INNER JOIN purchaseOrders c
            ON c.jobID = b.JobID AND
                c.time = b.maxVal
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c67d2/2)